# deploying in Julia Language

Tags: deployment, web-hosting, julia

I am trying to work through the Sudoku tutorial for the Julia language. http://iaindunning.com/2013/sudoku-as-a-service.html

Locally I an run their [`HttpServer.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/HttpServer.jl) web service, but how can I deploy things written in Julia language?

Google far as only returned [Forio](http://forio.com/julia/repl/) which doesn't let me deploy my own stuff.

Answer (score 2):

After trying many things, I ended up deploying my Julia code to AWS under an ec2 instance. I wrote about it here https://medium.com/@markhalonen/deploying-julia-1eb8a1686ca1

Answer (score 2):

We have recently made a [heroku julia buildpack](https://github.com/Optomatica/heroku-buildpack-julia). It is straightforward to use if your code is written in julia 1.0 or later. Just define your dependencies using `Project.toml`, `Manifest.toml` along with your code and It should be up and running.

It optimizes server booting time to 5 seconds only for a small application
[image]
For large applications, this can increase to around 30 seconds

Note: if you tried it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy Julia anywhere you get ssh access to a (virtual) machine connected to the internett. I am not aware of any companies that specialize in Julia for web hosting, but I think I remember hearing about cloud computing companies that will help you run Julia jobs on a cluster.

I would be very careful and assume that the machine might be hacked, because Julia is a young system and most of the developers do not have web grade security as their first priority. Making online systems secure is a huge effort and requires a level of interest and effort that the current development team does not seem to have.